# Sort by last name

Tags: python

How would I get the person with the first last name in the following:

```
l = ['John Fine', 'Doug Biro', 'Jo Ann Alfred']
--> Jo Ann Alfred
```

So far I was doing:

```
sorted(l, key=itemgetter(-1))[0]
```

Is this the recommended way to do this, or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are actually sorting by the last letter not the name, presuming the last word after a space is always the last name use split:

```
l = ['John Fine', 'Doug Biro', 'Jo Ann Alfred']

sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.rsplit(None,1)[-1])
```

If you just want the min value based on last name use `min`:

```
print(min(l,key=lambda x: x.rsplit(None,1)[-1]))
```

For the reverse use `max`.

`lambda x: x.rsplit(None,1)[-1]` actually splits the string on the last whitespace and uses that value as the key to sort.

Answer (score 4):

when you have to min, `min` don't `sort`:

`min(l, key=lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])`

**EDIT:**

I think a better solution will be: **1.** compare the last name, and **2.** if they are equal, compare the first. we can achieve that behavior easily with tuples:

```
min(l, key=lambda x:tuple(reversed(x.rsplit(None, 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ok for simple names,  but it is quite likely, in a large database of names, that there will be some exceptions, such as Charles (de Gaulle), which properly sorts as 'de Gaulle',  or Werner (Von Braun), but note,  Ludwig van (Beethoven).  The last two depend on the use of case on the 'v', yuuk. For more pedantry, see here...

> http://www.english-for-students.com/Listing-Names.html

So for an improved sort (still not complete) you need to have a dictionary to check against (if any) the last name minus one.

First check that the name has more than 2 words, then compare name[-2] against a list of extra sort words. If there's a match then sort the combined word

```
names=["Abraham Van Helsing", "Ludwig van Beethoven"]

def sortname(name):
   sort_prefix=['Van', 'Von']
   parts=name.split()
   if len(parts) > 2 and parts[-2] in sort_prefix:
       sortname = " ".join(parts[-2:])
   else:
       sortname=parts[-1]
   return sortname

print([sortname(x) for x in names])
```

Then you can use the same method as shown above working on the output of 'sortname(name)'.  It's a start, not a full analysis of the problem

In particular you will find that this will fail for a famous American scientist, **Robert Jemison (Van de Graaff)**,  requiring an extra level of testing.